# Codeigniter/xml-rpc - How to customise the XML request format?

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter, but I have been googling since the last 3 days but no chance.

Here is what the distant server is supposed to receive

```
Header content
(
    [0] => Content-type: text/xml
    [1] => Content-length: XXX
    [2] => User-Agent: XXXXX/4.1/1.0
    [3] => Authorization: Basic base64_encode("login:password");
)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
 <methodName>UpdateBalanceAndDate</methodName>
 <params>
  <param>
   <value>
    <struct>
     <member>
      <name>originNodeType</name>
      <value>
       <string>EXT</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originHostName</name>
      <value>
       <string>XXXX</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originTransactionID</name>
      <value>
       <string>XXXXXX</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originTimeStamp</name>
      <value>
       <dateTime.iso8601>XXXXXXX</dateTime.iso8601>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>subscriberNumber</name>
      <value>
       <string>XXXXXXX</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>transactionCurrency</name>
      <value>
       <string>XOF</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>adjustmentAmountRelative</name>
      <value>
       <string>XXXXX</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>transactionCode</name>
      <value>
       <string>11</string>
      </value>
      </member>
      <member>
       <name>transactionType</name>
       <value>
        <string>XXXX</string>
       </value>
      </member>
     </struct>
    </value>
   </param>
  </params>
 </methodCall>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And this is my code:

```
$this->load->library('xmlrpc');

$this->xmlrpc->server('server_ip_adress', 80);
$this->xmlrpc->method('UpdateBalanceAndDate');

$request = array('My Photoblog', 'http://www.my-site.com/photoblog/');
$request = array(
        array(
                array(
                        'originNodeType' => 'EXT',
                        'originHostName'=>'XXXX',
                        'originTransactionID'=>'XXXXXX',
                        'originTimeStamp'=>'XXXXXXX',
                        'transactionCurrency'=>'XOF',
                        'adjustmentAmountRelative'=>'XXXXX',
                        'transactionCode'=>'11',
                        'transactionType'=>'XXXX'
                ),
                'struct'
        )
);

$this->xmlrpc->request($request);

if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
{
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
}
```

Something is going wrong but I don't receive any error message from the server, I am checking the followings.

1. I need to customise the XML format of the request by adding a header
   to the default XML format. Is this possible in Codeigniter? How?
2. Is there any function in Codeigniter (or generally in PHP) which
   allows me to check the XML request before sending to the server?
   (Something like var_dump() or print_r() ).

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. Include any code you've already created. This will greatly increase your chances of a) getting an answer b) getting an answer that will actually help you.

Comment: Done! Any advise?